# How to recover locally committed changes(but not pushed to remote) after deleting branch from locally?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have done few changed in my branch which i committed locally but not pushed to remote..but mistakenly i removed that branch from local and then again fetch that branch from remote.

In this scenario how can i get changes which i committed locally?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git reflog --no-abbrev`.

Identify the last commit of of the deleted branch.

Do `git checkout -b <your-branch-name> <commit-hash>`

Comment: You mean `checkout -b <new-name> <commit-hash>`.

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Yes @torek. Not just `<new-name>`, but we can provide the same old deleted branch's name, right? Thanks for being one of the best git guide. I'll edit my answer as of now. Please feel free to suggest new edits.

Comment: Right, the name one deleted is fine here too. (By "new" I just meant "doesn't exist now".)